# Como se quitar atributo readonly de campos de una pagina a través de otra pagina con javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando quitar atributo readonly de unos campos de una pagina que se abre desde un botón de un menu , el problema es que puedo hacerlo desde un botón que se encuentra dentro de la pagina, pero si cuando intento abrirla desde un botón de un menu que esta en otra pagina, no me funciona la función.

Pagina menuOrdenes donde está el menú con el botón.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pagina crearOrdenes donde están los campos que deseo desbloquear.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pagina crearOrdenes que muestra que desde la misma pagina se puede desbloquear los campos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá dejo el código javascript del archivo ordenes.js

```
    function habilitarCampos(id,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6)
    {        
   // Eliminamos el atributo de solo lectura
    $("#"+id).removeAttr("readonly");
    // Eliminamos la clase que hace que cambie el color
    $("#"+id).removeClass("readOnly");

    // Eliminamos el atributo de solo lectura
    $("#"+id2).removeAttr("readonly");
    // Eliminamos la clase que hace que cambie el color
    $("#"+id2).removeClass("readOnly");

    // Eliminamos el atributo de solo lectura
    $("#"+id3).removeAttr("readonly");
    // Eliminamos la clase que hace que cambie el color
    $("#"+id3).removeClass("readOnly");

    // Eliminamos el atributo de solo lectura
    $("#"+id4).removeAttr("readonly");
    // Eliminamos la clase que hace que cambie el color
    $("#"+id4).removeClass("readOnly");

    // Eliminamos el atributo de solo lectura
    $("#"+id5).removeAttr("readonly");
    // Eliminamos la clase que hace que cambie el color
    $("#"+id5).removeClass("readOnly");

    // Eliminamos el atributo de solo lectura
    $("#"+id6).removeAttr("readonly");
    // Eliminamos la clase que hace que cambie el color
    $("#"+id6).removeClass("readOnly");

    }
```

Acá el código de la pagina donde se encuentra los campos
la pagina se llama crearOrdenes.jsp

```
         <nav id="primary-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center col-sm-6">
 <div class="left container-fluid">
     <div class="panel-heading bg-primary"><h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Ordenes</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">
            <form method="POST" action="generarOrdenServlet.do">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
        <thead class="input-sm">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" required name="txt_nombre_orden"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="SELECCIONE" name="txt_tipo_orden" required>
                               <option>Retiro</option>
                               <option>Entrega</option>
                    </select>
                    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" required name="txt_tipo_orden">-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <td><input type="date" class="form-control"   required name="txt_fecha_orden"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" required name="txt_desc_orden"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" required name="txt_cant_orden"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="SELECCIONE" name="txt_estado_orden" required>
                               <option>Pendiente</option>
                               <!--<option>RETIRADA</option>-->
                    </select>
                    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" required name="txt_estado_orden">-->
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>


                <th>Rut Cliente</th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="rutCliente" class="form-control"required name="txt_rut_clie_orden" value="<%=rutCli %>" readonly>
        </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
        <th>Nombre Cliente</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="nomCli" class="form-control" required name="txt_nombre_clie_orden" value="<%=nomCli %>" readonly></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <td><input type="phone"  id="phone" class="form-control" required name="txt_telefono_clie_orden" value="<%=telCli %>" readonly></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Direccion Cliente</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="dir" class="form-control" required name="txt_direc_clie_orden" value="<%=dirCli %>" readonly></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Email Cliente</th>
                <td><input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" id="email" required name="txt_email_clie_orden" value="<%=emailCli %>" readonly></td>

            </tr>



            <%

                    for(int i=0; i<usuario.size(); i++)
                    {
                        %>
                        <tr>
                <th style="display:none">Usuario</th>
                <td style="display:none"><input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<%=usuario.get(i).getIdUsuario() %>" required name="txt_usuario_orden" style="display:none"></td>

            </tr>
                        <%
                    }


            %>

            <tr>
                <th>Nº Reserva</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="nreserva" class="form-control"  required name="txt_num_reserva_orden" value="<%=numReserva%>" readonly></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Estacion</th>
                <td>
                    <!--<select class="form-control" placeholder="SELECCIONE" name="txt_cod_estacion" required>
                               <option>SCL</option>
                               <option>VAP</option>
                    </select>-->
                   <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_mostrar_id_estacion" required name="txt_cod_estacion">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning " data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEstaciones'>Ver Estaciones</button>
                   </div> 
                </td>

            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </table>
        <div class="container-fluid col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Generar</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="location.href='menuOrdenes.jsp'" class="btn btn-default "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Atras</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="habilitarCampos('rutCliente','nomCli','phone','dir','email','nreserva')"><span class=""></span> Limpiar</button>
            <!--<button type="button" onclick="habilitarCampos()">Habilitar</button>-->
        </div>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
     </nav>
```

Acá el código para llamar al archivo js. pagina menuOrdenes.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/ordenes.js"></script>
```

Acá el código de la otra pagina donde está el botón que habre la pagina anterior y que llama a la función para desbloquear los campos.
la pagina se llama menuOrdenes.jsp

```
<nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center col-lg-12"> 
<div class="left container-fluid">
```

```
  <div class="panel-heading bg-primary">MENU DE OPCIONES</div>
<div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="habilitarCampos('rutCliente','nomCli','phone','dir','email','nreserva')">
                    <a href="crearOrdenes.jsp"><img src="imagenes/img-ordenes.jpg" HEIGHT=200 WIDTH=100 class="img-responsive">CREAR ORDEN</a>
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
                    <a href="verOrdenesAgente.jsp"><img src="imagenes/img-ver-ordenes.png" HEIGHT=200 WIDTH=100 class="img-responsive">VER ORDENES</a>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
</div>
<button tupe="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='barraCentral.jsp'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Volver</button>
</div>
</nav>
```

El método solo me funciona al realizar desde la misma pagina donde están los campos a desbloquear , pero al hacerlo desde una pagina externa no funciona siendo que llamo al archivo js pero no funciona.
espero su ayuda gracias.

Comment: tal vez puedas usar **attr("readonly", false);** en lugar de **removeAttr("readonly");**

Comment: Hola, lo intente pero no funciona, solo se puede desde la misma pagina.

Comment: Si no, puedes verificar la ruta de tu src **./javascript/ordenes.js** o poner el error que te marca en la consola de tu navegador...

Comment: si , me dice lo siguiente Uncaught ReferenceError: habilitarCampos is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (menuOrdenes.jsp:28)

Comment: me indica que no está definido la función en el botón, pero si lo estoy llamando

Comment: puedes quitar el **.** de **./javascript/ordenes.js** y ver si ya no marca el error